# A timeout was reached (45000 milliseconds) while waiting for the MyService service to connect

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10, windows-services

I have developed a Win32 service (`SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS`) in C++ for Windows 10. It fails to start once in a while, with the following messages in the event log:

> A timeout was reached (**45000** milliseconds) while waiting for the MyService service to connect.
>
> The MyService service failed to start due to the following error:
>      The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

**What kind of timeout is happening here?**

I know that when a service starts up, there is a timeout of 30 seconds from the start of the executable to the call of `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`. I have a log statement just before the call to `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`, but I do not see it. Unfortunately, I do not have any log statements at the point where the service starts up. In between startup and `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`, I have a bit of initialization, but nothing that I would expect to take 30 seconds to finish.

My service never reaches `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` and I have not seen traces in the event log that it crashes.

So, why does the error message mention a timeout of 45 seconds and not 30 seconds? What does this timeout represent?

*Edit: For now I am mostly interested if other persons have experienced similar timeout and if they have figured out the reason. I need to debug my code, but I hope that someone might be able to give a direction in which I could concentrate my debugging in. Later I might need specific help with my code when I know where to look :-)*

*Edit: Microsoft describes many kinds of timeout in their API documentation for services. But I have not seen any mentioning of a 45 seconds timeout even if I have read all the API calls that I am using.*

Note: I have not modified any timeouts in the system/registry, if such a thing is possible.

Edit:
Notes about my service.

- The issue happens on a users pc that I do not have direct access to.
- My service starts up correctly most of the time, but when it fails, it might be during a windows update under boot-up, that causes it.
- In a virtual machine with a debug version of my service it takes less than 2 seconds from start of executable to call of StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(). That sounds reasonable. Far below 30 seconds and 45 seconds.
- I have in my development environment tried to add a delay (sleep) between start and StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() of greater than 30 seconds. This gave me the standard message about a 30000 miliseconds timeout. Not 45000!
- I have tried to force a crash between start and StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(). This gave me a "Application Error" event log entry about the crash and a standard 30000 seconds timeout. Not 45000! On the problem PCs eventlog I have not noticed any "Application Error" when the startup failed.

Comment: You are just going to have to debug your startup, add more logging, etc. Make sure your `main` is actually being called, and is actually attempting to initialize the process before calling `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`.  Maybe your app is crashing or deadlocking during initializing. There is no way for us to tell you.  That is what debugging is meant to figure out.

Comment: Check the `ServicesPipeTimeout` value at the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet`. Refer to [here for more info.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/839803/the-windows-trace-session-manager-service-does-not-start-and-event-id).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thanks for the info :-) 
I will try to check if this registry setting has been modified at the users pc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your comment. 
You are right that I need to debug my service, but I hope that someone might have experienced this before and could give me a direction, so I do not have to debug in 360 directions at once.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have tried to clarify my post a bit, I hope :-)
Regarding your suggestions I have tried to add a sleep to my startup and afterwards tried to force crash my startup. In both cases it gave a 30 seconds timeout. Not 45 seconds. See my post updates above. Regarding my service not starting at all... Maybe it could be that "Service Control Manager" does not even try to start my service. I will need to add a log statement to test that, and hope it can be reproduced. But what would a 45 seconds timeout represent in that case?

Comment: @NEOstergaard This issue seems occur at specified condition or environment. You can set [recovery action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/guidelines-for-services) to make the service restart after failure.